# Can no longer use SSH when port forwarding

Tags: ssh, routing, port-forwarding

I am using SSH, and have done so for a while. I have moved to a new place, and also have a new router. And now, I can only use the local IP for ssh. If I set up the port forwarding I previously had for external access through ssh, the local IP no longer works.

E.g. for one machine this command (connecting to a raspberry pi) works fine:

```
ssh -p 175 -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -i /Users/mfd356/Documents/02\ -\ WEB\ personal/Electronics/Raspberry\ pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt pi@192.168.0.175
```

After adding a rule to forwarding external port 175 to port 175 at local IP 192.168.0.175, then the previous command no longer connects.

But the same command with the external IP works just fine now:

```
ssh -p 175 -o "ServerAliveInterval 10" -i /Users/mfd356/Documents/02\ -\ WEB\ personal/Electronics/Raspberry\ pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt pi@REDACTED_EXTERNAL_IP
```

when debugging using the `-vvv` flag, I can see the following output when trying run ssh to local IP after forwarding ports:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mfd356/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/mfd356/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.175" port 175
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.175 [192.168.0.175] port 175.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/Documents/02 - WEB personal/Electronics/Raspberry pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/Documents/02 - WEB personal/Electronics/Raspberry pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

without port forwarding, it tells me:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mfd356/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/mfd356/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.175" port 175
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.175 [192.168.0.175] port 175.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/Documents/02 - WEB personal/Electronics/Raspberry pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/Documents/02 - WEB personal/Electronics/Raspberry pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.175:175 as 'pi'
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.0.175]:175
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.0.175]:175
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zB2UjmMfpMtI494ax62CuXKIntFFAHQf9z1FyFG0/zk
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.0.175]:175
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.0.175]:175
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.0.175]:175
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.0.175]:175
debug1: Host '[192.168.0.175]:175' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mfd356/.ssh/known_hosts:34
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key:  (0x7fbfe0f01460), agent
debug2: key: /Users/mfd356/Documents/02 - WEB personal/Electronics/Raspberry pi/ssh/privatekeyopenssh.txt (0x0), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/mfd356/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fbfe0e01070), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: 
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:TJJsIeUGyaBKkNkSkrHaSml1NXsdipIiwqNbElWXNng
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:TJJsIeUGyaBKkNkSkrHaSml1NXsdipIiwqNbElWXNng
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.0.175 ([192.168.0.175]:175).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

But I can't make anything from the `-vvv` output. It's weird to me, since I have not changed anything in the setup (like config files i.e. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), since this worked. Just the router has changed, but it's the same brand of router (now Sagemcom fast 3890, can't remember the old model name), and it's the same internet provider as well.

Any ideas?